# Moq setup confusion in C#

Tags: c#, moq

So I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
  internal void A() {
    foreach(Thing thing in ThingArray)
      B(thing);
  }

  virtual internal void B(Thing thing)
  {
    //  do some stuff
  }
}
```

And then I have the following test:

```
...
var testObject = new Mock<MyClass>(parameters);
testObject.Setup(t => t.B(It.IsAny<Thing>()));

test.Object.A();

test.Verify(t => t.B(It.IsAny<Thing>()), Times.Exactly(2));
```

And the verify is failing.  I've checked, and the code is calling the **real** B() method as opposed to a mocked B() method.

I've got a lot of code running where Moq works perfectly, and I've been coding long enough to realize that I must be doing something wrong here, but for the life of me I can't see it.  I've been proceeding under the assumption that since I'm calling test.**Object**.A(), the calls to B() are not going through the Mock, but that really doesn't make any sense to me since a call from any other object would work the same...

So why on earth isn't the mocked setup being executed?

Edit:  Yes, I have the internals visible to the test project.  I meant to put that into the original post, since I knew someone would mention it.

As to the real code, it is unfortunately VERY proprietary, so I can't post it.  I'll see if I can adjust the code tomorrow to make it actually compile.

Comment: Hmm Can you give us like a mini example of code that we can just pop in and run. I tried to take what you had and changed "Thing" to a string object but there is no t.B() that shows up so I don't know if something that you gave in the code has a typo or what. Since it does not show up in intellisene. Also when I usually do my mocking I usually have a interface and I pass in that interface through my constructor. Like I am not sure how your actually passing this mock object to MyClass. Since however I seen it you got to pass it in through like property injection, constructor inject or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Gamlor's answer works.  It seems that if you want to perform a setup on a method where you want to verify that Class1.MethodA calls Class1.MethodB, MethodB (which is the one you would do the setup on) has to be public (regardless of InternalsVisibleTo).  I wrote a simple test under a similar situation and found that once I made my MethodB public, Moq started working.  I would bet if you made your method B public, it would work.

I assume this is a Castle or Moq bug but I don't know for sure.  Hopefully somebody will chime in.

I know making MethodB public is not a good choice.  But that is what I know about the situation...

Comment: I did eventually determine the same thing; There are a number of other things that require public as opposed to "InternalsVisibleTo" - unfortunately in this case you don't get an error as much as you just get odd behavior.
I ended up breaking the class into two pieces, which I suppose makes more sense; the public class is visible to the world, the second class is private and allows testing.

Answer (score 7):

The object your Mock has to meet this criterias in order to make a successfully mock a method:

- It has to be an interface
- Or the method you want to mock has to be a virtual method and public.

Now you can also mock virtual-internal method, but in order to allow that you have to give Moq access to your internals. This you can do with:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

This make the internal accessible to the code-generator of Moq.

So in order to mock your `MyClass.A` call you have to do this:

1. Make you method A virtual.
2. And make your method public or allow access with

   ```
   [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
   ```

Or as said, make an interface which represents the API of MyClass.

Comment: A() is actually the method under test.  Which is why I call test.Object.A() - I wanted to be able to test that particular method.  I wanted to be able to test it without testing B(), which was why I ended up with the strange circumstances I have.

I'm starting to think that my testing approach is flawed in this case, but I'm fairly new to this TDD thing...

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: `DynamicProxyGenAssembly32`.  Was pulling my hair out after adding an `InternalsVisibleTo("Moq")` and still getting nowhere :D

Answer (score 0):

Moq doesn't wrap the existing code, but instead creates an empty mock.

That means that calling testObject.Object.A() doesn't execute your original code, so B is never called.

If you pretend your mocking an interface then this makes sense because interfaces don't have code, so neither would the mock.

Comment: That's the odd thing...  It is calling the original code.  I tossed some exceptions into the A() and B() methods, and the exceptions were thrown.  Also, wouldn't Moq create a derived class from the Mocked class?  Which would mean that any non-virtual methods (like my example A()) would be called on the base class anyway.  Or is the mocking done via reflection?...  I don't think that would work since the mocked class would not be type-qualified as the original base class.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the mock like this (I didn't try it so I don't know if it works):

```
var testObject= new Mock<MyClass> { CallBase = true };
```